# Tridion SmartTarget claim processor

Tags: 2011, smarttarget

I am new to SmartTarget 2011 and have a couple of questions:

1. Can we specify "NamespaceName.ClassName' for ImplementingClass if the claim processor is in the .Net dll?
2. Does the claim processor always be in Java instead of .NET (by implementing `ClaimProcessor` interface)? The reason I am asking this is because everywhere I am seeing it being written in Java. To me it seems we can write in .NET as well. Please confirm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the Content Delivery side of Tridion APIs that you call, can normally be called from .NET and Java. But plugins that you create and Tridion calls, are normally in Java only (unless you do your own interop).

For #2: as far as I know you can only write ClaimProcessors in Java.

Comment: So how it finds the java class if the implementionclass is specified as com.tridion.... do the jar file need to have the same name as the cartridge file to reach the class ?

Comment: I would recommend reading a bit more about how it works - your question seems to be based on wrong assumptions (I never had to use com.tridion for my claims). Eric Huiza has some good stuff (http://erichuiza.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/ambient-data-framework-in-nutshell.html), and of course so does the documentation (http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-F2948DF0-95FE-4B46-995E-0B13B7FAAA3D).

Comment: And here's an example of a claim processor I wrote: https://github.com/NunoLinhares/TridionContextEngineWrapper/blob/master/com/sdl/tridion/context/personalization/c2c.xml

Comment: Ok. I saw your implementation class as "com.sdl.tridion.context.personalization.SetClaimsAsCharacteristics", which must be in some jar file. How ADF finds that particular jar file.

Comment: It finds it in the classpath - standard java functionality. You compile the jar and add it to your \bin\lib folder. You jar file can be named anything, the JRE will search for a class with the required name in the classpath, irrelevant of file names.

Comment: Frank: "For #2: as far as I know you can only write ClaimProcessors in Java. "     Your assumtion is correct.